# MySQL-python-Calculator Tips

Tags: python

I’m unable to get the output I want.
This is how far I was able to get:

```
bill = int(input())
print (125 /100 *20)
```

I’m still learning how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty straightforward. Everything is mentioned. To calculate 20% of an amount multiply it by 20 and divide it by 100.
Your input method is right but since `bill` can also be a `float`, using the `float` data type would be better. The error is in the print statement as you are, for some reason, dividing 125 rather than the `bill` you input.
Correct Code:

```
bill = float(input()) # taking a float input is a better option as the bill might be a float
print(bill*20/100) # tip = bill * 20 / 100
```